# Receiving Start Error after using Py2App on a script that uses subprocess

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I brand new to OSX operating system, and I'm simply trying to launch a piece of java code from Python.

I'm using the following code:

```
import os 
import subprocess

subprocess.call([os.getcwd() + '/contents/home/bin/java', 
                '-jar', 
                os.getcwd() + '/Whoo.jar'])
```

It works exactly as expected when run as a script. However, when I package everything with Py2App, I suddenly get an error when attempting to run the app.

#### Build process for the app:

```
py2applet --make-setup test.py
```

and then,

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

Note: No errors are noted in the terminal during the build process.

Upon starting the app I get the following:

[image]

#### Console output:

```
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]    argvemulator warning: fetching events failed
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]    Traceback (most recent call last):
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]      File "/Volumes/FLASH_DRIVE/App/start.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 342, in <module>
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]        _run()
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]      File "/Volumes/FLASH_DRIVE/App/start.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 335, in _run
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]        exec(compile(source, script, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]      File "/Volumes/FLASH_DRIVE/App/start.py", line 7, in <module>
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]        os.getcwd() + '/Whoo.jar'])
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]        return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]        errread, errwrite)
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]        raise child_exception
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  [0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2/21/13 6:08:06 PM  start[5230] start Error
2/21/13 6:08:10 PM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[94]   ([0x0-0x32c32c].org.pythonmac.unspecified.start[5230]) Exited with exit code: 255
```

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the current working directory under the py2app converted application is different from when calling it directly.

Try logging the value of `os.getcwd()` to see where it does start from

Quite possibly the working directory will be somewhere inside the `<application>.App/Contents` folder, so if you aren't copying resources into the .App bundle, you may have to go up two or three directories to find the resources (best practice is to have all resources inside the Application bundle).

Comment: The default working directory for the applications generated by py2app is <application>.app/Contents/Resources.